# Get list Post with comment and user's info in Spring JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two model:

Model Post:

- id
- content
- user_id
- type
- timestamp

Model Comment:

- id
- message
- user_id
- type
- timestamp
- post_id

I don't know how to retrieve posts of posts that contain comments and information user. Because user information in two different tables. Distinguish through `type` field. I have two tables that store user information, user and admin.

Thank you !

UPDATE:

Class Post

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1)
    @Column(name = "content", nullable = false)
    private String content;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "author_id", nullable = false)
    private Long authorId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false) 
    private Long type;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
    private Long status;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "classroom_id", referencedColumnName = "id") 
    private ClassroomBO classroomBO;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "postBO", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<CommentBO> comments;
```

Class comment

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1)
    @Column(name = "content", nullable = false)
    private String content;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "author_id", nullable = false)
    private Long authorId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false) 
    private Long type;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false) 
    private Long status;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id", referencedColumnName = "id") 
    private PostBO postBO;
```

And I have two table user: users and student. i want join with it to get info user and check type feild in post or comments.

Comment: Share your code and what have you done so far because we can’t help you without it

Comment: i updated code on question. Thanks for reading and help !

Comment: Share more details about how are you querying these model? There are various ways that people do it. What is your approach? Where are you stuck? Are you getting any errors? etc....

Comment: Sorry. Currently, I have no solution to the problem. Can you give me solution ? Thanks @BalajiSrinivasan